# How to convert a count of days between two dates as numeric in OracleSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using this query

```
select current_date - table.DOB/365 as checkagainst
```

to get the days between today's date and a person's date of birth. It is returning what looks like a numeric count of days, but then when I try to divide it by 12, I get the error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE.
```

I just want to divide the date difference between a DOB and today's date by 365 to get age in years.

Answer (score 1):

Use parentheses:

```
select ( current_date - table.DOB )/365
```

Or, better yet, use `months_between()`:

```
select months_between(table.DOB, current_date) / 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between dates returns number of days between two dates.

So use following:

```
Floor(Sysdate - table.DOB) -- number of days
Floor(Months_between(sysdate, table.DOB)) -- number of months
Floor((Months_between(sysdate, table.DOB)/12) -- number of years
```

Floor will make sure to show the rounded to the nearest small number as age should be.

Cheers!!